# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DB_USER environment variable

Tags: python, django, postgresql, environ

This project was working good until I reinstalled django-environ to make DB_USER, exc
After I tried to execute and I had this error ...

`settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os 
import environ

env = environ.Env(
    #Set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)

"""if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    environ.Env.read_env()"""

#reading .env file
#environ.Env.read_env()

#False if not in os.environ
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

`DATABASES FROM settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env("DB_NAME"),
        'USER': env("DB_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': env("DB_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': env("DB_HOST"),
        'PORT': env("DB_PORT"),
    }
}
```

`.env file` it is located at the same directory like `settings.py`

```
DEBUG=False
SECRET_KEY='KEY'
DB_NAME=DB
DB_USER=USER
DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
DB_HOST=HOST
DB_PORT=
```

And error

```
File "D:\CRM\web\settings.py", line 96, in <module>
    'USER': env("DB_USER"),
  File "D:\CRM\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.get_value(
  File "D:\CRM\env\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 407, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DB_USER environment variable
(env)
```

```
#I deleted the comment. SOLVED!
environ.Env.read_env()
```

Comment: why did you comment out your environ.Env.read_env() line?

Comment: I tried to check. Otherwise, I had a problem with .env file. So at this moment it works.

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```
env = environ.Env(
    #Set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False) )
```

add this

```
environ.Env.read_env()
```

Comment: Yes, I have but I commented this line. It was working until I have added new line in .env file.

Comment: can you share the .env file at least but changing your secrets ??

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error and fixed it with:

````
"NAME": env("DJANGO_DB_NAME", default=''),, JUST ADD default='' in all ```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).